# error: cannot find jdk library path

Tags: java, ubuntu, hdf5

I'm on an ubunutu machine and when I try to run:

```
./configure  --enable-parallel --enable-fortran  --enable-cxx
```

I get this error:

```
configure: error: cannot find jdk library path.
```

I have added the path of jdk to both LIB_PATH and LD_LIB_PATH.

```
/soft/hdf-java-2.11.0$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/bin/glnxa64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/lib:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/lib/amd64/jli:/usr/lib64
/soft/hdf-java-2.11.0$ echo $LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/lib:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/lib/amd64/jli
```

I had the same problem with the header files but when I edited the include flags it solved the problem. not sure why the same thing with the libraries are not working.

Comment: You might read the configure script to see how it is looking for the jdk library, and under which name. It might expect JAVA_HOME to be set to the directory above lib.

Comment: Hi Laune I tried that still same results

Comment: what are you configuring and what part uses java? pls give more details, the only stuff i found on web is asking to set jdk_lib (sounds app sepecific)

Comment: Kalpesh:
I'm trying to install HDF5 from its https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/release/obtainsrc.html

not sure what other info you need

Answer (score 0):

the solution is:

./configure --with-jdk=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include,/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/lib --prefix=$HOME